"Most of the antibiotics these days go to the chickens raised for eggs." Source?
One of the most common arguments for veganism rather than vegatarianism is that supposedly most of the antibiotics these days go to egg-laying chickens, rather than to animals raised for meat. Therefore, vegetarianism isn't actually doing much to prevent superbacteria. But is there a reliable source claiming that?
The claim certainly seems plausible, if not very probable. After all, here is a source saying that, in Chile, around 70% of eggs contain small amounts of antibiotics:

Cornejo et al. [13] reported that 73% of eggs collected from backyard production systems in the central region of Chile exhibited antimicrobial activity for tetracyclines, beta-lactams, aminoglycosides, and macrolides confirming the presence of antibiotic residues.
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2468227622003611

I believe I've read somewhere that it's around 25% of eggs in the USA, but I cannot find that source right now. That's by more than an order of magnitude more common than in dairy, as only around 1% of randomly-chosen milk samples test positive for antibiotics.
Ideally, such a source should take into account the fact that not all antibiotics used in egg-laying chickens can be used in humans, so they don't really cause "superbacteria" in any useful sense of that word.

"not all antibiotics used in egg-laying chickens can be used in humans, so they don't really cause "superbacteria"" And yet those antibiotics get inside humans, when they eat the eggs. I do not see the connection between your two statements. If the chicken antibiotic gets into the human body, it will probably kill something, but not something else. The something else could be the "superbacteria". Please add some details to the question, if possible.

@virolino Resistance to one class of antibiotics doesn't cause resistance to another class of antibiotics.

Not in a direct cause-effect manner. But the mutation which causes the immunity to one antibiotic might also create immunity to another antibiotic. And let's not ignore the damage done to the human being by the antibiotics which are not suitable for humans. If they do not harm people by creating superbacteria, they create problems simply by being unsuitable - and here I am just using the information you provided in the question. Btw, these are just comments, I am not able to answer the core of the question.
